# Invalid column name when using dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I want to execute the following T-SQL dynamic statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MergeTable @TableName NVARCHAR(max) 
AS BEGIN
DECLARE @MergeStatement NVARCHAR(max)
SET @MergeStatement = 'SELECT Query FROM dbo.QueryMergeDWH WHERE SourceTableName = ' + @TableName
EXEC sp_executesql @MergeStatement
END

EXEC MergeTable @TableName = 'SGPREINVOICE'
```

However, this gives me the following error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 17 Invalid column name
> 'SGPREINVOICE'.

This actually works:

```
SELECT 'SELECT Query FROM dbo.QueryMergeDWH WHERE SourceTableName = ' + 'SGPREINVOICE'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: not quoting it in the dynamic case.

Comment: **WARNING**: This is a *huge* injection issue. You are giving a malicious person the ability to inject **2 billion bytes** (1 billion characters) of *whatever* SQL they want. If this is executed under an `LOGIN`/`USER` with high enough permissions they could *literally* do **anything** they wanted with minimal effort. ***NEVER*** inject unsanitised strings into a dynamic statement and *don't* use `MAX` for an object's name. There is a specific data type for object names: `sysname`.

Comment: Here's an parameterized query example that will address your problem and improve security: `SET @MergeStatement = N'SELECT Query FROM dbo.QueryMergeDWH WHERE SourceTableName = @TableName';EXEC sp_executesql @MergeStatement, N'@TableName nvarchar(523)', @TableName = @TableName;`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parameterize you dynamic query. So you pass `@TableName` all the way through

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE MergeTable @TableName NVARCHAR(max) 
AS

DECLARE @MergeStatement NVARCHAR(max);

SET @MergeStatement = '
SELECT Query
FROM dbo.QueryMergeDWH
WHERE SourceTableName = @TableName;
';

EXEC sp_executesql
    @MergeStatement,
    N'@TableName nvarchar(max)',
    @TableName = @TableName;

GO
```

But it's unclear what's dynamic about that, you could just as well do

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE MergeTable @TableName NVARCHAR(max) 
AS

SELECT Query
FROM dbo.QueryMergeDWH
WHERE SourceTableName = @TableName;

GO
```